# How to call nested structs in c sharp

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Hello everyone I'm trying to create nested structs then use it but I can't do it

what I've done is

```
public struct number
        {
            int[] linenumber;


            public struct information
            {
                public linenumber name, surname, id, phone;

            }
        }
```

what I'm trying to do is create an array of line number and each number in the stack should hold the name surname id and phone information..

to use this i write number inf = new number();
and then try to inf.linenumber[n].name // where n is my counter.. but it doesn't work, any ideas what i have to do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this.

```
public struct number
    {
        public information[] linenumber;


        public struct information
        {
            public string name, surname, id, phone;

        }
    }
```